# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth' - Firebase & Firestore integration with Python App

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-colaboratory, buildozer

I'm trying to integrate google Firebase (Firestore) to my mobile app which is written in Python and Kivy.
When I tried it on the computer (in Pycharm) everything works great and I can read and write to my Firestore database, but when I'm building an APK using Buildozer and Google Colab the app crashes and I get the above mentioned error.
the error lines are as follow:

```
File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 40, in <module>
File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/MyApp/firebase_admin/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/MyApp/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 20, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth'
```

I added 'google.auth' module and almost any other google related module to the Buildozer.spec requirements and nothing worked...
there is any problem with the requirements in the Buildozer.spec file?
Or it is related with the importing of modules?

Thanks